# Does my hardware support 4TB disk with ubuntu server

Tags: server, hardware, storage, fujitsu-siemens

I just installed my first Ubuntu Server on some old server hardware, a  Fujitsu Primergy TX200 S6.

I want to make a NAS solution with this and maybe install plex in the future or something else.

My question now is: I have two 2TB disk and four 4TB disk installed in it but when I do

```
sudo lshw -class disk -short
```

it shows me all my disks but it looks like the 4TB disk only use 2TB each.

Did I miss something? Does Ubuntu server support 4TB disks ? Does my hardware support 4TB disks? I looked at the specs and did not find anything that said it did not support.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ubuntu server support 4TB disks ?

Yes, Linux has support for a lot larger disks. But there is a something to note:

- You need a UEFI BIOS to use as boot drive that is over 2TB.
- The limit of about 2TB is typical for MBR partitions. You need GPT.

> Does my hardware support 4TB disks?

We do not provide support for hardware. But to  get you going: the name of the system is not important. You need to check the name of the BIOS and its version, and that it is UEFI to be able to boot from it.

Comment: it is possible to use GPT with BIOS too, but a small trick needs to be done.